# How to move many repos to a new github organization

Tags: python, node.js, github, automation, repository

I have an organization with many repos (300 +) and I expect this number to grow. Therefore, from time to time, I want to clean up my organization but I would like to avoid deleting the repositories.

So right now my idea of cleaning up would be, to transfer repos that are depricated to a different organization, where I can still keep them and transfer them back, if needed, but the number of repos in the original organization goes down to ~50 or so.

I am aware of the possibility to transfer ownership within github, however repeating the process 250 times seems like a nightmare to me and I would like to automate this (there is no API endpoint to do so afaik).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this or ever encountered a similar task?

Thanks for your help!

(In terms of automation any solution that includes python or nodejs would be preferred over other languages)

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2017, transferring the repo ownership is not available from the API. See this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/117).

Because of that no tool can automate this task (if it wants to follow the official API instead of for example scraping the website etc. which would be against the TOC).

But you can ask about it in the support channels, maybe someone can help you on an individual basis.

Answer (score 1):

This [github-api-bulk-transfer](https://github.com/jdbean/github-api-bulk-transfer)
seems to solve exactly that problem. It also notes that: *An UNSUPPORTED AND UNSTABLE PREVIEW feature for repository transfer has recently been introduced to the GitHub API that allows this process to be automated* so I would proceed with caution.